# Gazebo on Windows 10 error when running

Tags: installation, windows

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've managed to build Gazebo as per the [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows&cat=install) (although it has taken me every evening for nearly a week hint for others use CMake version 3.2.3, I had problems with versions above and below that).

When I attempt to run the server I'm getting the output below. Does that provide any indication of what the specific problem could lie other than most likely something to do with Ogre?

I am now in the process of downloading and building the Ogre samples to make sure they run on my machine but I thought I'd check if the console output provided a likely pointer to the Gazebo problem at the same time.

> F:\gz-ws\gazebo\build\gazebo>gzserver.exe --verbose ....\worlds\empty.world
> Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.1.0
> Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
> Released under the Apache 2 License.
> http://gazebosim.org
>
> [Msg] Waiting for master.
> [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
> [Msg] Publicized address: 10.1.1.2
> [Err] [F:\gz-ws\gazebo\gazebo\rendering\RenderEngine.cc:125] EXCEPTION: Unable to create an Ogre rendering environment, no Root
>
> [Err] [F:\gz-ws\gazebo\gazebo\rendering\RenderingIface.cc:38] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
> Unable to create an Ogre rendering environment, no Root
> [Err] [F:\gz-ws\gazebo\gazebo\gazebo.cc:86] Unable to load sensors
> [Err] [F:\gz-ws\gazebo\gazebo\Server.cc:275] Unable to load gazebo
> [Err] [F:\gz-ws\gazebo\gazebo\transport\Connection.cc:274] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application requestValue[995]
>
> F:\gz-ws\gazebo\build\gazebo>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13277/gazebo-on-windows-10-error-when-running/) by [azaclauson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2592/azaclauson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I stumbled across the log file in C:\Users\username.gazebo\ogre.log and saw the attempt to load dll's from C:\Users\username\gz-ws\ogre_src_v1-8-1-vc12-x64-release-debug\build\install\Debug\bin\Debug (the path provided in the install instructions).

Changed the paths in the plugins.cfg files to the location I did the Gazebo build:
PluginFolder=F:\gz-ws\ogre_src_v1-8-1-vc12-x64-release-debug\build\install\Release\bin\Release

And now gzserver runs!

Running the gzclient still gets a crash but I'll look into that separately.

---

Originally posted by [azaclauson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2592/azaclauson/) with karma: 35 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0